# Copying to system clipboard with vim not working under Ubuntu

Tags: vim, ubuntu-12.04

I have been trying to figure out why when I use "*y or "*x in one terminal window running vim and "*p in another it doesn't paste what I had just copy or cut and just can't figure it out.

I know that * is the system clipboard buffer, but it will not copy between terminal windows.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 with Vim 7.3.

Answer (score 5):

Use `:version` to see what features are included (`+`) or not (`-`).

If you see `-clipboard` and `-xterm_clipboard` then it's not going to work.  You could compile vim yourself including those features, or you could install `vim-gtk` through:

```
apt-get install vim-gtk
```

Comment: Really the only way to make this work is to compile it myself? there has got to be some other way

Comment: Ah I got it, I had to get the vim-gtk package

Comment: I see you have a solution, but for the record, you can start gvim as `gvim -v` and it will start in terminal mode, so that you'll have a terminal vim with X11 features enabled.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK that only works in `gvim` - not in `vim` running in a terminal.

Comment: It works in the terminal version, but needs the compilation switch mentioned in Matthew Cline's answer. The "beefier" Vim packages in the mainstream distributions come with this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

From the [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VimHowto) website:

> NOTE: As of Ubuntu 6.10 (Edgy Eft), the default Vim install is a
> cut-down version called "vim-tiny". In order to get the full version
> complete with the online help documentation, and many of the advanced
> functions such as code folding; you will need to install "vim":

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

This should install a (much!) better build of vim, allowing you to do the clipboard cut/paste from terminals. (I do it all the time).  You might also install the '*vim-gtk*' package to obtain the GUI build, sometimes it's handy to have (I map '*Meta-V*' to open gvim for me, hotkeys for the win!)

(There is no need to uninstall the '*vim-tiny*' package, it's kinda 'absorbed' into the '*vim*' and '*vim-gtk*' packages)